# Python script to open URL with access code (APS)

Tags: python, authentication, automation, urllib

I am trying to write a script in python to access the content of the following page:

https://authors.aps.org/Submissions/status/

what I tried so far was to use urllib.urlopen in the following way:

```
import urllib

access_code = 'XXXXXXX'
author = 'xxxxxxx'
url = 'https://authors.aps.org/Submissions/status/'
login_data = {
            'accode':access_code,
            'author':author,
            'submit':'Submit'
        }

login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_data).encode('utf-8')
urllib.request.urlopen(url, login_data)
```

But I always get

```
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to send your encoded `login_data` as a POST request?

Comment: Yes, even though these are not really private credentials (username and password).

Comment: I think you actually want a GET request as opposed to a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

access_code = 'XXXXXXX'
author = 'xxxxxxx'

login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    'accode': access_code,
    'author': author
})

url = 'https://authors.aps.org/Submissions/status?utf8=%E2%9C%93&commit=Submit&{login_data}'.format(login_data=login_data)

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Unfortunately this resultls in

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad request

Comment: The exact script above works on my computer using python 3. Print the url and make sure it looks like this: `https://authors.aps.org/Submissions/status?utf8=%E2%9C%93&commit=Submit&accode=XXXXXXX&author=xxxxxxx`

Comment: Great, thanks! I had forgotten to implement your modifications in the definition of login_data... Now it works!